# Slow TimescaleDB query using time_bucket

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, postgresql-11, timescaledb

I have a simple database (PostgreSQL 11) filled with millions of data. I want to get average `value` per day. For that I am using `time_bucket()` function.

### Database schema

```
-- create database tables + indexes
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS machine (
    id   SMALLSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reject_rate (
    time       TIMESTAMPTZ UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    machine_id SMALLINT REFERENCES machine(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    value      FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(time, machine_id)
);
CREATE INDEX ON reject_rate (machine_id, value, time DESC);

-- hypertable
SELECT create_hypertable('reject_rate', 'time');

-- generate data with 54M rows
-- value column is generated randomly
-- this tooks minutes to finish but that's OK
INSERT INTO machine (name) VALUES ('machine1'), ('machine2');
INSERT INTO reject_rate (time, machine_id, value)
   SELECT to_timestamp(generate_series(1, 54e6)), 1, random();
```

The query I am trying to do is:

### Query

```
SELECT
time_bucket('1 day', reject_rate.time) AS day,
AVG(value)
FROM reject_rate
GROUP BY day
```

### Result + EXPLAIN

Runtime of the query is very slow even if I use indexes. **Query returns 626 rows and takes 26.5 seconds to finish**. 90 TimescaleDB chunks have been created. Here's the EXPLAIN statement of this query:

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=41.17..5095005.10 rows=54000000 width=16)"
"  Group Key: (time_bucket('1 day'::interval, _hyper_120_45_chunk."time"))"
"  ->  Result  (cost=41.17..4015005.10 rows=54000000 width=16)"
"        ->  Merge Append  (cost=41.17..3340005.10 rows=54000000 width=16)"
"              Sort Key: (time_bucket('1 day'::interval, _hyper_120_45_chunk."time"))"
"              ->  Index Scan using "45_86_reject_rate_time_key" on _hyper_120_45_chunk  (cost=0.42..14752.62 rows=604800 width=16)"
"              ->  Index Scan using "50_96_reject_rate_time_key" on _hyper_120_50_chunk  (cost=0.42..14752.62 rows=604800 width=16)"
"              ->  Index Scan using "55_106_reject_rate_time_key" on _hyper_120_55_chunk  (cost=0.42..14752.62 rows=604800 width=16)"
"              ->  Index Scan using "60_116_reject_rate_time_key" on _hyper_120_60_chunk  (cost=0.42..14752.62 rows=604800 width=16)"
"              ->  Index Scan using "65_126_reject_rate_time_key" on _hyper_120_65_chunk  (cost=0.42..14752.62 rows=604800 width=16)"
"              ->  Index Scan using "70_136_reject_rate_time_key" on _hyper_120_70_chunk  (cost=0.42..14752.62 rows=604800 width=16)"
"              ->  Index Scan using "75_146_reject_rate_time_key" on _hyper_120_75_chunk  (cost=0.42..14752.62 rows=604800 width=16)"
+ ~80 another rows of Index scan
```

### Question

Did I create indexes correctly? Did I create the database correctly? Or is just TimescaleDB slow like that for this amount of rows?

This is possibly the reason why `time_bucket()` is slow: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1229. The proposed solution is to use a *continuous aggregated view*. Is this the recommended way how to use time-series in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Continuous aggregate view is expected to help. TimescaleDb helps a lot if queries contain conditions on time column, since it will exclude chunks, which are outside the time range.

Comment: Your query performs full scan over all the rows. Try using other time series databases such as [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com) or [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - they can show better query performance. Also I'd recommend trying analytical databases such as [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.yandex) - is has [up to 100x better full scan performance](https://clickhouse.yandex/#performance) comparing to conventional databases.

Comment: facing the same issue, time_bucket really slow down query response

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how long it would take with the built-in Postgres functions:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', rr.time) as day,
       AVG(value)
FROM reject_rate rr
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', rr.time);
```

Comment: It takes approximately same time (it is few seconds slower only).
But my goal is to work with time-series, time buckets should be more suitable for this. I might want to change the time bucket for something else.

Comment: Hi @MichalŠpondr can you post your EXPLAIN just to make sure nothing seems amiss?  

But the high-level observation is that your query is simply doing a full scan over all your data -- nothing really to filter out from your chunks (say, if you added `WHERE time > now() - interval '1 week'`) -- so you are primarily testing the scan over the 54M rows.  In that case, performance often highly a function of disk/memory throughput.  Do you continue to see the same performance if you repeat the request?

Comment: @MikeFreedman I've added EXPLAIN to the original post. Performance is same if the query is repeated. The truth is I scan all 54M of rows. But I was expecting this is optimized somehow.
Perhaps the time_bucket is not meant to be used to efficiently compute aggregates over whole dataset.